# How to Add and activate PPTP or L2TP VPN connection?

Tags: android

i am developing the one SIP based application to make and receive a calls. In which i need to access a PPTP VPN connection because in some countries VOIP and SIP are blocked.If i use VPN connection then calls will not block even VOIP and SIP are blocked in that country. So how do i add a new PPTP VPN connection?

Answer (score -1):

Open Network and Sharing Center >> Set up a new connection or network >> Connect to a to workplace >> create a new connection   >> use my internet connection vpn >> enter vpn and click next

[image]